# Undefined method on mock object implementing a given interface in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, mocking, phpunit

I'm new to unit testing and PHPUnit.

I need a mock, on which I have a full control, implementing `ConfigurationInterface` interface. Test subject is `ReportEventParamConverter` object and test must check the interaction between my object and the interface.

`ReportEventParamConverter` object (here simplified):

```php
class ReportEventParamConverter implements ParamConverterInterface
{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param ConfigurationInterface $configuration
     */
    function apply(Request $request, ConfigurationInterface $configuration)
    {
        $request->attributes->set($configuration->getName(), $reportEvent);
    }

    /**
     * @param ConfigurationInterface $configuration
     * @return bool
     */
    function supports(ConfigurationInterface $configuration)
    {
        return 'My\Namespaced\Class' === $configuration->getClass();
    }
}
```

And this is the way I'm trying to mock the interface:

```php
$cls = 'Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ConfigurationInterface';
$mock = $this->getMock($mockCls);
```

I need to simulate the returned values for two methods: `getClass()` and `getName()`. For example:

```php
$mock->expects($this->any())
    ->method('getClass')
    ->will($this->returnValue('Some\Other\Class'))
;
```

When i create a new `ReportEventParamConverter` and test `supports()` method, i get the following PHPUnit error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Mock_ConfigurationInterface_21e9dccf::getClass().

```php
$converter = new ReportEventParamConverter();
$this->assertFalse($converter->supports($mock));
```

Comment: Does the `ParamConverterInterface` has the `getClass()` method?

Comment: @hakra does that matter?

Comment: Please answer the question to add more information to your question. That would matter. Apart from that, it would be my first assumption why the mock does not have that function. So some basic debugging.

Comment: @hakra, no it doesn't. And `getClass()` is never invoked on any `ParamConverterInterface` instance.

Comment: It is invoked in the `supports()` method, isn't it?

Comment: @hakra invoked in the `supports()` method on the `ConfigurationInterface` instance, not on the `ParamConverterInterface`. So there is no method `getClass()` in `ParamConverterInterface` and it shouldn't.

Comment: I have mixed interface names, is `getClass()` in `ConfigurationInterface` then? No, it is not: https://github.com/sensio/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/Configuration/ConfigurationInterface.php - so it does not exists.

Comment: @hakra no, there isn't. Apparently the method should be there (as per documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html)...

Comment: As it does not exists, I assume (have not checked the mock's library code) the mock does not add a stub method for it. As it gets called (via `supports()`, PHP will throw the fatal error as the function does not exists in the stub.

Comment: @hakra thanks for helping, it was the missing method then.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's because there is no declaration of "getClass" method in ConfigurationInterface. The only declaration in this interface is method "getAliasName".

All you need is to tell the mock what methods you will be stubing:

```
$cls = 'Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ConfigurationInterface';
$mock = $this->getMock($cls, array('getClass', 'getAliasName'));
```

Notice that there is no "getClass" declaration but you can stub/mock non existing method as well. Therefor you can mock it:

```
$mock->expects($this->any())
    ->method('getClass')
    ->will($this->returnValue('Some\Other\Class'));
```

But in addtion you need to mock "getAliasName" method as well as long as it's interface's method or abstract one and it has to be "implemented". Eg.:

```
$mock->expects($this->any())
   ->method('getAliasName')
   ->will($this->returnValue('SomeValue'));
```

Comment: So if methods doesn't exist in the original class should be declared in `getMock()` call? If the method exists then it's not necessary?

Comment: You always should tell to mock which methods you are going to stub/mock. If you don't specify that, the mock assume that you will stub all methods from the class (eg. if you specify just one method methodA, $mock = $this->getMock('Class', array('methodA')), the mock assume that you mock ONLY methodA, and when you call another method: $mock->methodB(), then "real" method from "Class" is executed)

Answer (score 13):

Cyprian's answer helped me, but there's a gotcha to be aware of. You can mock classes that don't exist, and PHPUnit won't complain. So you could do

```
$mock = $this->getMock('SomeClassThatDoesntExistOrIsMisspelledOrPerhapsYouForgotToRequire');
```

This means that if `ConfigurationInterface` doesn't exist at that point during runtime, you'll still get a message like

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Mock_ConfigurationInterface_21e9dccf::getClass().

**If you're sure the method really exists on the class, then the likely problem is the class itself doesn't exist (because you haven't required it, or you misspelled it, etc).**

---

The OP is using an *interface*. Be advised that you must call `getMock` without specifying the list of methods to override, or if you do, you must either pass `array()`, or pass ALL the method names, or you'll get an error like the following:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class Mock_HttpRequest_a7aa9ffd contains 4 abstract
>   methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the
>   remaining methods (HttpRequest::setOption, HttpRequest::execute,
>   HttpRequest::getInfo, ...)

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this, it was indeed a missing class that was causing me problems.

Comment: Thanks. Had the same problem.

Comment: I experienced this while mocking an external library that was `require`d in the class under test, but not conforming to the autoloader.

Comment: Thanks for point this out. I used a class with only class name which included in the use, but it turns out needs to provide the full namespace of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Tyler Collier's warning is fair but doesn't contain a code snippet on how to code around it. Note this is very nasty and you should fix the interface instead. With that warning added:

```
$methods = array_map(function (\ReflectionMethod $m) { return $m->getName();}, (new \ReflectionClass($interface))->getMethods());
$methods[] = $missing_method;
$mock = $this->getMock($interface,  $methods);
```