# Mocking security.context is considered like a non-object when calling

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, testing, phpunit

I'm trying to test my service. This service calls other service like `security.context`. When the `AlbumHandler` is call, the mock fail at the `security.context` step.

Error:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getToken() on a non-object
```

Code:

```
     public function setUp()
     {
        $this->container = $this->getMock('\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface');
     }


      public function testAdd()                                                                 
      { 

        // The user I want to return                                                                                        
        $user = $this->getMock('\MyProject\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User');  

        // I create a Token for mock getUser()                    
        $token = $this->getMock('\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token');       
        $token->expects($this->once())                                                          
              ->method('getUser')                                                               
              ->will($this->returnValue($user));                                                

        // I mock the service. PHPUnit don't return an error here.
        $service = $this->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface')
              ->disableOriginalConstructor()                                                    
              ->getMock();  
        $service->expects($this->once())                                                        
              ->method('getToken')                                                              
              ->will($this->returnValue($token));                                               

        // I replace the real service by the mock
        $this->container->set('security.context', $service);                                

        // It fails at the constructor of this service.
        $albumHandler = new AlbumHandler($entityManager, $this->container, 'MyProject\Bundle\AlbumBundle\Entity\Album');

        $this->assertEquals($albumHandler, $albumHandler);                                    

      }
```

The following code is the constuctor of AlbumHandler

```
  public function       __construct(ObjectManager $om, Container $container, $entityClass)  
  {                                                                                         
    $this->om = $om;                                                                        
    $this->entityClass = $entityClass;                                                      
    $this->repository = $this->om->getRepository($this->entityClass);                       
    $this->container = $container;

    // fail here                                                       
    $this->user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();         
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must mock the container get call too. Try Substitute this:

```
    // I replace the real service by the mock
    $this->container->set('security.context', $service);
```

with

```
    $this->container
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('get')
        ->with('security.context')
        ->will($this->returnValue($service));
```

Hope this help

EDIT:

You muck the wrong `Token` Object. Substitute:

```
    // I create a Token for mock getUser()
    $token = $this->getMock('\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token');
```

With:

```
    // I create a Token for mock getUser()
    $token = $this->getMock('Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface');
```

Comment: Thanks @Matteo! but now, I got an error a the next step: `.PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Mock_Token_66794207::getUser()`. Do you see something wrong in my code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599957/undefined-method-on-mock-object-implementing-a-given-interface-in-phpunit helped me too!

Comment: BTW, use `$this->container->get('security.authorization_checker')` instead (new in 2.6)